# Improving performance

Tags: angularjs, django

I am new in AngularJS. I developed a list that can be filtered when typing in a search box. the filter takes many fields from a database object and search through all of these fields (such as: name, id, comments ... etc).
The problem appears when I load all of the queryset and fill the list in the angular method using the (push) command.
since I have a considerable amount of records in the database, loading the page takes around 12 seconds, and the database is increasing so this time is going to grow!
I tested the performance using the time line and as expected, the scripts are taking a very long time!

Here is a piece of my code:

Template

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ngApp.controller('FilterCtrl', function ($scope) {


        $scope.lines = [];

        {% for line in lines %}

            $scope.lines.push
            ({
                id:{{ line.id }},
                name: '{{ line.name }}',
                alias: '{{ line.alias }}',
                owners: '{{ line.print_owners }}',
                interested_in: '{{ line.print_interested_in }}',
                crosses_count: '{{ line.related_crosses_count }}',
                area: '{{ line.expressions }}',
            });

        {% endfor %}    
  });

</script>
```

views:

```
def browse_lines(request):
     lines = Line.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('name')

     return render_to_response('Browse_Lines.html',
                          {'lines': lines },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any way to improve the performance and speed up filling the list?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered some kind of pagination (i.e. only returning the first `x` records)?

Comment: On the database end obvious improvement is adding indexes for the fields you use for such query.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Pagination doesn't fulfil the requirement of the website. That is why I can't use it.
The filtering process should go through the complete data at once.

Comment: @Nikita
I will check your suggestion right now thank you.

Comment: @Nawwar Mokayes, you can do that from Django side via [`db_index`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index) field option. Indexes have a drawback - they have to be calculated and this takes time, depending on database size it might be significant, but the queries will work faster. Also, you might want to read [Django docs section on performance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/performance/).

Comment: ...then *mention that*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick win would be to stop pushing things to the array one by one

```
$scope.lines = [
{% for line in lines %}
   {
        id:{{ line.id }},
        name: '{{ line.name }}',
        alias: '{{ line.alias }}',
        owners: '{{ line.print_owners }}',
        interested_in: '{{ line.print_interested_in }}',
        crosses_count: '{{ line.related_crosses_count }}',
        area: '{{ line.expressions }}',
    },
{% endfor %}    
];

</EndUglyCode>
```

Now the correct way would be to make a separate get request to fetch the data as you require it (for which there are plenty of angular examples around including on the angular homepage).

Pagination would **definitely** be a good idea but at the very least you can splice the initial results so you're not returning N objects all the time

```
 lines = Line.objects.filter(deleted=False).order_by('name')[:10]
```

If you really feel that you need to return all lines then you should consider if ordering them is required since this is likely to make up a hefty chunk of the time.

Comment: Yea, I am checking your suggestion, it seems to be working.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of 'speeding up'.

The best way would be to paginate your table such that initially the data would be loaded only for the first page. Say, you have 1000 items, divide it into pages of say 100 items each. So, initially only the first 100 items will be fetched. When you go to a different page the next 100 items and so on.

Also, for filtering you will to write an api endpoint which would accept the filter query and return items from the database. Then show these items in your table. As for when to hit this api, use the combination of `ngChange`, `ngModel` and `ngModelOptions`(for debounce) like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.query" ng-change="getItems()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" />
```

Here, `getItems()` will be called when the user types in something and waits for 1s (handled by debouce). In that function, send `search.query` to the api.

Comment: Thank you.
Actually, the pagination is not sufficient for the idea of the search because the filtering should go through the complete data at once.